# Difference between php and python mongodb adapter

Tags: php, python, mongodb, pymongo

I have code in php which reads example record from mongodb:

```
<?php
$client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db = $client->foo;
$collection = $db->bar;
$item = $collection->findOne();
var_dump($item);
```

And similar code in python:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.foo
collection = db.bar
item = collection.find_one()
print(item)
```

When I run php script i get expected result:

```
array(11) {
  '_id' => class MongoBinData#6 (2) {
    public $bin => string(10) "somestring"
    public $type => int(3)
  }
  'a' => double(62051.444165621)
  'b' => int(974386)
  'c' => string(10) "some string"
  ... some int, float  and string fields ...
  'tags' => array(0) {}
}
```

But, python script return error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 5, in <module>
    item = collection.find_one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 724, in find_one
    for result in cursor.limit(-1):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1058, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1002, in _refresh
    self.__uuid_subtype))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 940, in __send_message
    self.__compile_re)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 117, in _unpack_response
    compile_re)
bson.errors.InvalidBSON: invalid length or type code
```

Why I can read data in php script and can't read data in python?
Is it possible to read this data in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have stored some data in MongoDB that PyMongo considers corrupt, but the PHP driver does not. If possible, please use "mongodump" to dump only the offending document, or as few documents as possible, and attach it to a new bug report. When you describe the problem, please tell us how you **stored** the data: what driver version, what programming language, what code you wrote to create the document. Register and click "Create Issue" at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON

Comment: Thanks. I save invalid data n mongo. Bug details are here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-787